# Java BufferedImage.getRGB () - Coordinate out of bounds

Tags: java, bufferedimage

So, I'm trying to the color of a specific pixel in an BufferedImage...

```
public void LoadImageLevel (BufferedImage image) {

    int w = image.getWidth ();
    int h = image.getHeight ();

    System.out.println (w + " " + h);

    for (int xx = 0; xx < h; xx++) {

        for (int yy = 0; yy < w; yy++) {

            int pixel = image.getRGB (xx, yy);

            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;

            if (red == 255 && green == 255 && blue == 255) {

                handler.addObject (new Block (xx * 32, yy * 32, ObjectID.Block, 32, 32));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it's called from the Main class constructor:

```
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader ();

    level = imageLoader.loadImage ("/levels/level_test.png");

    LoadImageLevel (level);
```

The BufferedImage is loaded from my BufferedImageLoader class:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage (String path) {

        try {

            image = ImageIO.read (getClass ().getResource (path));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace ();
        }

        return image;
    }
}
```

When I run the project I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:   Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
    at com.main.index.Game.LoadImageLevel(Game.java:190)
    at com.main.index.Game.<init>(Game.java:41)
    at com.main.index.Game.main(Game.java:206)
```

Line 190 is the "int pixel = image.getRGB (xx, yy);", line 41 is where it's called in the constructor, and line 206 is the main method.

---

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Answer (score 4):

Problem is here:

```
int pixel = image.getRGB (xx, yy);
```

It should be:

```
int pixel = image.getRGB (yy, xx);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `xx` goes from 0 to the height, instead of going from 0 to the width. Your `yy` goes from 0 to the width, instead of going from 0 to the height.

Comment: Thanks, didn't even realize that... Thx :D !

Answer (score 1):

```
level = imageLoader.loadImage ("/levels/level_test.png");
```

The Image you are using should be less than total Width and Height of main Window . And In this case Where RGB values are taken A picture with size of 2^X where X = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.... ..

Try this :
resize level_test.png to 512 by 512 pixels.

Above is solution for this as Array contains boundaries.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:   Coordinate out of bounds!
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
```